# Bypassing print dialogue box cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have searched and I thought I had found the answer for which I was looking but alas, it's still not working correctly.  The app generates a window and launched the print dialogue box and waits for the user to click print when it should just print without the dialogue.

```
    - (IBAction)print:(id)sender {

NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];

NSPrinter *printer;
printer = [NSPrinter printerWithName:@"Brother QL-710W"];
NSSize size;
size.width = 94;
size.height = 288;

[printInfo setPrinter:printer];
[printInfo setTopMargin:0.0];
[printInfo setBottomMargin:0.0];
[printInfo setLeftMargin:0.0];
[printInfo setRightMargin:0.0];
[printInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];
[printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSFitPagination];
[printInfo setOrientation:NSPaperOrientationLandscape];
[printInfo setPaperSize:size];

NSPrintOperation* printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:PrintView];
[printOperation setCanSpawnSeparateThread:YES];
[printOperation runOperationModalForWindow:theLabelWindow delegate:theLabelWindow didRunSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
[printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
[printOperation setShowsProgressPanel:NO];

//Reset the label window contents
//AppDelegate *printItDamnit = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
//[printItDamnit resetLabel:self];

//GO!
[printOperation runOperation];

//Get rid of the label window because we're done with it ;)
[theLabelWindow close:self];}
```

Shouldn't this eliminate he dialogue?

```
[printOperation setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
```

Comment: Don't call `runOperationModalForWindow`.

Comment: Well, by not calling `runOperationModalForWindow` the job is printed without any dialogues.  Unfortunately the settings aren't honored and the job comes out all wonky...  I guess it's not possible to bypass the dialogue and still print with specific settings?  Specifically, the quality of the print and the size and orientation are all off.

Comment: Call `setShowsPrintPanel` and `setShowsProgressPanel` before `runOperationModalForWindow` and don't call `runOperation`.

Comment: Well, I tested it every which way and while it is totally possible to print without any dialogue I have yet to find a way to successfully pass any of the `[printInfo ]` settings to the printer.  It seems that bypassing the dialogue defaults the settings and the custom settings are ignored.  Bummer.

Comment: Inspect `printInfo` before run and after run in the delegate method. Do the same with a dialog.